# Adding footer view to each group of an MvxExpandableListView

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to add a footer view to each group list of an MvxExpandableListView.

The AddFooterView method just adds to the bottom of the entire list.

I have been trying to create a custom adapter that inherits from MvxExpandableListAdapter so that I could try and add it myself.
But, I am getting "Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0" when the list is loading, and the stack trace looks like it is using the original MvxExpandableListAdapter and not the new one I have created.

My activities OnCreate

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.WorkOrderListing);
        SetupToolbar();
        SetupNavigationMenu(Resource.Id.nav_work_orders);

        _listView = FindViewById<MvxExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.listing_workorders);
        var adapter = new LoadMoreExpandableListAdapter(this, BindingContext as IMvxAndroidBindingContext);

        _listView.SetAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

List View in my layout file

```
<Mvx.MvxExpandableListView
android:id="@+id/listing_workorders"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:dividerHeight="@dimen/expandablelist_divider_height"
android:childDivider="@color/line_grey"
android:contentDescription="WorkOrderListing_ExpandableList"
android:groupIndicator="@null"
local:MvxGroupItemTemplate="@layout/workorderlisting_header"
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/workorderlisting_detail"
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource WorkOrderLists; GroupClick GroupClickCommand; ItemClick ItemClickCommand" />
```

My adapter, (just trying to have the minimum of code to get it working before I try to add the footers)

```
public class LoadMoreExpandableListAdapter : MvxExpandableListAdapter
{
    #region Constructors

    public LoadMoreExpandableListAdapter(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public LoadMoreExpandableListAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext) : base(context, bindingContext)
    {
    }

    protected LoadMoreExpandableListAdapter(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    public new View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        object rawItem = this.GetRawItem(groupPosition, childPosition);
        return this.GetBindableView(convertView, rawItem, this.ItemTemplateId);
    }

    public new View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        object rawGroup = this.GetRawGroup(groupPosition);
        return this.GetBindableView(convertView, rawGroup, this.GroupTemplateId);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in this block of code for MvxExpandableListView

```
protected MvxExpandableListAdapter ThisAdapter {
  get {
    return this.ExpandableListAdapter as MvxExpandableListAdapter;
  }
}
```

Stack Trace

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x000a8] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.g.cs:11687
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0006b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods_Invoke.cs:355
  at Android.Views.LayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x00054] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Android.Views.LayoutInflater.cs:653
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxLayoutInflater.Inflate (System.Int32 resource, Android.Views.ViewGroup root, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x0003e] in <0bd205dc7a7f4d20ae563bf31b6b4c87>:0
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.CommonInflate (System.Int32 resourceId, Android.Views.ViewGroup viewGroup, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x00012] in <0bd205dc7a7f4d20ae563bf31b6b4c87>:0
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.MvxAndroidBindingContext.BindingInflate (System.Int32 resourceId, Android.Views.ViewGroup viewGroup, System.Boolean attachToRoot) [0x00000] in <0bd205dc7a7f4d20ae563bf31b6b4c87>:0
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.CreateSimpleView (System.Object dataContext) [0x00006] in <0bd205dc7a7f4d20ae563bf31b6b4c87>:0
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.GetSimpleView (Android.Views.View convertView, System.Object dataContext) [0x00003] in <0bd205dc7a7f4d20ae563bf31b6b4c87>:0
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxAdapter.GetBindableView (Android.Views.View convertView, System.Object dataContext, System.Int32 templateId) [0x00003] in <0bd205dc7a7f4d20ae563bf31b6b4c87>:0
  at MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxExpandableListAdapter.GetGroupView (System.Int32 groupPosition, System.Boolean isExpanded, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent) [0x00011] in <0bd205dc7a7f4d20ae563bf31b6b4c87>:0
  at Android.Widget.IExpandableListAdapterInvoker.n_GetGroupView_IZLandroid_view_View_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Int32 groupPosition, System.Boolean isExpanded, System.IntPtr native_convertView, System.IntPtr native_parent) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/c1d1c79c/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-24/src/generated/Android.Widget.IExpandableListAdapter.cs:472
  at at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:3046abf5-3522-4b43-8977-6eb130a28c37 (intptr,intptr,int,bool,intptr,intptr)
  at android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
  at at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
  at at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
  at at md5bf0126c95bf9fc0db24c02c9adb4cfa7.MvxExpandableListAdapter.n_getGroupView(Native Method)
  at at md5bf0126c95bf9fc0db24c02c9adb4cfa7.MvxExpandableListAdapter.getGroupView(MvxExpandableListAdapter.java:150)
  at at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
  at at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
  at at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
  at at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
  at at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
  at at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
  at at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
  at at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
  at at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1187)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
  at at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
  at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
  at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
  at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
  at at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
  at at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
  at at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
  at at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
  at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
  at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please include the stack trace

Comment: Stack trace added

Comment: Added list view xml from layout